# Deleting Files in Eclipse causes every image to be wrong

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, r.java-file

Just what the title says if I delete any file out of the drawable folder when I run the game every image is another image, so I've got menu screens as characters, and weapons as buttons - its like all the addresses get totally screwed up

I've tried Project -> Clean as well as deleting the gen folder (which is then regenerated) but it has had no effect at all

Can someone please help me, right now every single file I add to a project has to remain there forever or the whole project is broken...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen sometimes but Project > Clean is all you need to do to fix it. Make sure that the correct project is selected in the clean dialog.

Comment: yep, I've selected it and even selected "clean them all"
I've deleted every image, saved, and reuploaded them into the drawable folder, and that has had no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `R.java` and Rebuild project. It would re-generate `R.java` which contains all id of resources

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the project from eclipse but not the source code. And then create a new android project by selecting the 'create from existing code' option. This worked for me once when the rest failed.